# Configuring Email notification alert for Azure Devops PAT token expiration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automation

Im working on PAT Lifecycle Management API to get details of PATs in an Azure Devops Organization and send a remainder mail to team on expiring PATs

Im able to get the PAT details but how can I automate sending a notification for the team before a month or week of it's expiry

Comment: Hi, have you got a chance to check the suggestion below? If the answer is helpful for you, you may consider [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#notifications), **Users** receive **two** notifications during the lifetime of a PAT - one upon creation and the other seven days before the expiration.

Currently there is no built-in way to send notification email to **team** on expiring PATs. For this, you may access this URL: https://aka.ms/AzDevOpsIdeas to submit any comments and proposals for future releases and implementations.

By the way, if you are using this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) to list the PATs in an organization, please be noted that you will only get the details of the PATs that created by the user who generated the bearer token for authentication to call the API, rather than all the PATs of all users in this organization.